# Election results 2011

Tags: discussion, election

Raw output from MeekSTV voting (I hope):

```
OpenSTV version 1.7 (http://www.OpenSTV.org/)

Suggested donation for using OpenSTV for an election is $50.  Please go to 
http://www.OpenSTV.org/donate to donate via PayPal, Google Checkout, or
Amazon Payments.  

Certified election reports are also available.  Please go to 
http://www.openstv.org/certified-reports for more information.

Loading ballots from file election-results.blt.
Ballot file contains 8 candidates and 96 ballots.
No candidates have withdrawn.
Ballot file contains 96 non-empty ballots.

Counting votes for TeX - LaTeX Moderator Election 2011 using Meek STV.
8 candidates running for 3 seats.

 R|Seamus         |Matthew Leingan|Konrad Rudolph |Stefan Kottwitz|Caramdir       |Joseph Wright  
  |               |g              |               |               |               |               
  |---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------+---------------
  |Martin Scharrer|lockstep       |Exhausted      |Surplus        |Threshold      
  |               |               |               |               |               
==================================================================================================
 1|       2.000000|       4.000000|       4.000000|      28.000000|      12.000000|      26.000000
  |      13.000000|       7.000000|       0.000000|       5.999998|      24.000001
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count of first choices. Candidates Stefan Kottwitz and Joseph Wright have reached the
  | threshold and are elected.
==================================================================================================
 2|       2.142857|       4.406589|       4.681316|      24.791212|      13.186804|      25.318682
  |      13.934060|       7.395601|       0.142879|       2.181332|      23.964281
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Stefan Kottwitz, 0.857143 and Joseph Wright, 0.923077.
==================================================================================================
 3|               |       5.549446|       4.681316|      24.791212|      13.186804|      25.318682
  |      14.934060|       7.395601|       0.142879|       2.181332|      23.964281
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Seamus and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
==================================================================================================
 4|               |       5.727259|       4.936555|      24.455258|      13.661977|      24.214077
  |      15.299266|       7.534158|       0.171450|       0.755059|      23.957138
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Stefan Kottwitz, 0.828553 and Joseph Wright, 0.873698.
==================================================================================================
 5|               |       6.727259|               |      25.388459|      13.959726|      25.387360
  |      16.299266|       7.705605|       0.532325|       3.041981|      23.866919
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Konrad Rudolph and transferring votes. All losing candidates are
  | eliminated.
==================================================================================================
 6|               |       6.999909|               |      24.396760|      14.714326|      24.356357
  |      16.796386|       7.960415|       0.775847|       1.141039|      23.806039
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Stefan Kottwitz, 0.778898 and Joseph Wright, 0.821373.
==================================================================================================
 7|               |       7.106332|               |      23.989418|      15.001404|      23.987736
  |      16.985164|       8.059016|       0.870930|       0.412618|      23.782268
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Stefan Kottwitz, 0.760039 and Joseph Wright, 0.802815.
==================================================================================================
 8|               |               |               |      24.899326|      16.241365|      24.790551
  |      17.225125|       8.298977|       4.544656|       3.962203|      22.863837
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating Matthew Leingang and transferring votes. All losing candidates are
  | eliminated.
==================================================================================================
 9|               |               |               |      26.569272|      18.241365|      25.593366
  |      19.705047|               |       5.890950|       7.108112|      22.527263
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after eliminating lockstep and transferring votes. All losing candidates are eliminated.
==================================================================================================
10|               |               |               |      23.456946|      20.083794|      23.507748
  |      21.184125|               |       7.767387|       2.848386|      22.058154
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Stefan Kottwitz, 0.644414 and Joseph Wright, 0.706638.
==================================================================================================
11|               |               |               |      22.454266|      20.841763|      22.363926
  |      21.769620|               |       8.570425|       1.103404|      21.857394
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Stefan Kottwitz, 0.605987 and Joseph Wright, 0.663064.
==================================================================================================
12|               |               |               |      21.990282|      21.137315|      21.982661
  |      22.000378|               |       8.889364|       0.640341|      21.777660
  |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  | Count after transferring surplus votes. Keep factors of candidates who have exceeded the
  | threshold: Stefan Kottwitz, 0.589879 and Joseph Wright, 0.648046. Candidate Martin Scharrer
  | has reached the threshold and is elected.

Winners are Stefan Kottwitz, Joseph Wright, and Martin Scharrer.
```

Comment: Is the raw ballot data available?

Comment: @TH. Yes: http://tex.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/1. I just grabbed that and the analysis program and hoped I've get it right (no official results yet, I think)

Comment: Thanks!

Comment: I for one welcome our new moderator overlords...

Answer (score 6):

The final and official results are in: https://tex.stackexchange.com/election/1

Winners are Stefan Kottwitz, Joseph Wright, and Martin Scharrer.

### [image]


[image] 
[image]

411 voters were eligible, 142 visited the election, and 96 voted

Comment: For some reason the `election/1` site lists me before Joseph but links the image to Joseph's and his image to my user account.

Comment: this is now fixed

Comment: Thanks @Geoff !

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all for your confidence!

The many great candidates show that we are an outstanding community.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting: the [election statistics page](http://se.awio.com/election.html) by Yi Jiang shows a different result, at least for now.

Comment: I suspect it just picks up on who the current moderators are, on the basis that after the election they should be the winners.

Comment: The site obviously took the easy way out.

Comment: It looks like so, because other sites with only one previous moderator as candidate only show this one as elected and no-one else.